# Can't retrive contents of files inside a subdirectory

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Well I have a code that handles some txt files with data in them
The file inserts the data into the database with some more details 
the problem is that when i added **glob()** to the equation (so it can handle all the data files inside a directory called data)
 I had a problem with the **file_get_contents()** function 
Here's the code I use :

```
    <?php
//Database connect 
$sql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','torrents+');
foreach(glob("data/*.txt") as $file) {
$filename = substr($file, 5,-4);

//Get Data
$text = file_get_contents('/'.$file.'');



foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $line) {
$data = explode("|", $line);
$magnet = $data[0];
$name = $data[1];
$magnet = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:".$magnet."&dn=".$name."";

//Variables definition
$Name = $name;
$Category = $filename;
$Size = "_";
$date = time();
$Seed = "_";
$Leech = "_";
$hits = "0";


//Insert
$query = "INSERT INTO `torrents` (id, name, category, size, date, seed, leech, magnet, hits) VALUES (' ','$name','$Category','$Size','$date','$Seed','$Leech','$magnet','$hits');";
$sql->query($query) or die($query.'<br />'.$sql->error);

}



echo "<h1>Done with file ".$file." !!!!</h1>";
}

?>
```

And here are the errors I get :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/data/Games Mac.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\...\localweb\Scripts\handle.php on line 8


Warning: file_get_contents(/data/Games Mobile.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\...\localweb\Scripts\handle.php on line 8
```

Comment: as the file names have spaces windows requires tey are quoted

Comment: so what should I change

Comment: as Dagon pointed out, you need quotes since it has spaces: try `('"/'.$file.'"')`